# What is the significance of spiders in 2013 movie Enemy?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, enemy

How should one interpret the recurring appearance of giant spiders in the  2013 film [***Enemy***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2316411/), starring Jake Gyllenhaal? What is the meaning of the last scene?